# docker build is not work

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I can't seem to get `docker build` to run correctly:

```
wangyaos-MBP-3:~ wangyao$ cd /Users/wangyao/Ozintel/docker/flexcloud/
wangyaos-MBP-3:flexcloud wangyao$ ls
Dockerfile      apache-tomcat-7.0.62    jdk1.8.0_45.jdk
wangyaos--3:flexcloud wangyao$  docker build -t="Users/wangyao/Ozintel/docker/flexcloud" .
Invalid namespace name (Users). Only [a-z0-9-_] are allowed.
wangyaos-MBP-3:flexcloud wangyao$ cd /Users/wangyao/
wangyaos-MBP-3:~ wangyao$  docker build -t="Users/wangyao/Ozintel/docker/flexcloud" .
Cannot locate Dockerfile: Dockerfile
wangyaos-MBP-3:~ wangyao$  docker build -t="Users/wangyao/Ozintel/docker/flexcloud"
docker: "build" requires 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.
Usage: docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
Build a new image from the source code at PATH
```

How should I use `docker build`?

Answer (score 4):

Slow down and take a look at the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/).

To use `docker build`, the easiest way is to cd into the directory with the Dockerfile then run something like:

```
$ docker build -t flexcloud .
```

The `-t` argument specifies the repository name and tag, not the directory with the Dockerfile. If you want to give a path to a different Dockerfile, you can use the `-f` argument. The `.` at the end specifies the "build context", in this case the current working directory.